# How to pass ajax post response to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a page index.php - > It has php code, jquery code and php code all in one.

```
$.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: "post",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
                success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    if (data.result) {

                     // I want to store this data.result and pass it to PHP code below.
                       $("#some-form").submit();
                    } else {
                    // some code here
                    }
                },
                error: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    // Show a modal informing user of invalid 
                       information

                }
})
```

I see correct data in success block in data.result.
I want to pass this value to my php code below :

```
<?php
  function buildRedirectUrl($url) {


    return $url .
                 "&email=" . trim($_POST["email"]) .                     
                 "&state=" . trim($_POST["state"]) .                   
                 "&application_code=" . 
              trim($_POST["application_code"]);


     // I want to add the data.result from success block here
     // something like :
     //   "&result=" . trim($_POST["data.result"]) . 

   }

    $redirectUrl = buildRedirectUrl($someUrl);
    header('Location: ' . $redirectUrl);
 ?>
```

Any solution ?
Is it possible to pass data from ajax call to php?
Any example will be helpful. I found all examples that access the inputParameters but I did not see any example as to how I can use the response in php

Comment: I'm guessing that if you remove the `JSON.stringify` if works just fine? Then again, I have no idea what you're trying to do ?

Comment: I am able to make a successful POST request. I see correct result in success block. I want to store the response data.result and access it in my PHP code.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? you would need to store the result in `#some-form` before submitting it.  Why would you do anything in ajax in the first place.  Just submit the form with inputData.

Comment: I want to auto populate that field in another html page that I am redirecting to using header()...

Comment: Working on an existing code base that has this type of pattern :(

Comment: just try to set that data.result to a hidden elements value  and see whats happening . you are submitting after an ajax request anyway. Weird !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE: this code is not fully functional and just a concept.**

I guess if you have to you could do something like this;

```js
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: "post",
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
  success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    if (data.result) {
      //following 3 lines are new.
      var elem = $("<input type='hidden' name='ajaxResult' />");
      elem.val(data.result);
      $("#some-form").append(elem);
      // I want to store this data.result and pass it to PHP code below.
      $("#some-form").submit();
    } else {
      // some code here
    }
  },
  error: function(data, status, xhr) {
    // Show a modal informing user of invalid 
    information

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you could use the result in your form post `$POST["ajaxResult"]`

Comment: It did not give any error but it gave a blank value

Comment: It worked. I made a typo in my code. Thank you very much. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamically a form and submit it like below

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "post",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            if (data.result) {
                var method = "post";
                var action = "site.com/index.php";
                var form = document.createElement("form");
                form.setAttribute("method", method);
                form.setAttribute("action", action);
                var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "field_name");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("value", data.result);
                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
                document.body.appendChild(form);
                form.submit();

            } else {
            // some code here
            }
        },
        error: function(data, status, xhr) {
            // Show a modal informing user of invalid 
               information

        }
})
```